# <audio> Как запомнить место воспроизведения трека, как на видео youtube?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, аудио, web-audio

На youtube есть опция, которая запоминает, до какого момента проигрался данный трек, и потом пользователь может вернуться к просмотру с данного места, а не с самого начала.

Как сделать такую опцию для audio на сайте? Может у кого есть пример кода?

Comment: Ну, к примеру (но пример, пожалуй, глупый), можно на событие `ontimeupdate` писать функцию которая возвращала бы время на `beforeundload` окна, к примеру - в `localStorage` записывать время на это событие; а потом просто проверять - если там есть время то воспроизводить начиная с него и удалять его с `localStorage`

Comment: А сколько времени может храниться информация в localStorage?

Comment: @VladZaev, localStorage на бесконечно (до очистки браузера), sessionStorage на сессию

Answer (score 2):

На youtube для запоминания текущей позиции времени используется пункт меню правой клавиши **копировать видео URL с привязкой по времени**. В этом случае в конец URL добавляется гетзапрос типа **&t=15**. Похоже можно задавать в аудио, даже без имени переменной и знака равняется, типа такого адреса страницы: **http://site.ru?15**

```html
<audio id=audio src="1.mp3" controls></audio>
<script>
var curTime = location.search.substring(1);
document.getElementById("audio").currentTime = curTime;
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Я уже реализовал это через LocalStorage: пишу туда текущие позиции ползунка трека и вермени, и с них загружаю аудио в следующий раз.